# <?php phpinfo();?> test does not work

Tags: php, lamp

[image][image][image: screenshot]

I have no background in PHP, I don't have a public IP address nor a domain, but I want to create a website; to install LAMP I followed the instructions [here](http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2014/06/how-to-install-lamp-in-ubuntu-server-14-04-lts.html), but my script does not seem to work.

I have tried adding a little space after the parenthesis symbol, but I get the error as the one on the image.

Comment: Not sure if this tutorial is correct. I don't see mod_php in there. Do you have `libapache2-mod-php5` installed? Have you restarted Apache after installing php? Or reloaded: `sudo service apache2 reload`?

Comment: I tried with the additional space too. and I saw another post and I installed libapache2-mod-php. Let me try reload. I'll tell you in a moment

Comment: Is the IP address I'm using correct isn't it? 127.0.0.1

Comment: The problem seems to be Apache here. If it was PHP to not be working either the source code or a blank page would be displayed, I don't remember exactly, but for sure not a 404.

Comment: Can you see the Apache test? it worked but not the php

Comment: Reload didn't work, Did you see the second image?

Comment: Where did you put the .php file? It should be in the DocumentRoot directory and readable by apache.

Comment: Ok, then you're probably putting in the wrong address. The root directory for Apache in the latest versions is `/var/www/html`. That corresponds to `127.0.0.1`. If you put the file in say `/var/www/html/phptest` you'll need to go to `127.0.0.1/phptest/phpinfo.php`.

Comment: This is Exactly what I did:

Testing PHP5 and MySQL
In order to test PHP script you need to create simple PHP script in directory /var/www/html. in this case I’ll create phpinfo.php:

sudo touch /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
sudo nano  /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
Add the following line into file /var/www/html/phpinfo.php

<?php phpinfo(); ?>
Save and Test the php script you have made from web browser by typing in address bar http://ip_address/phpinfo.php. It will appear like screenshot on below.

Comment: Would you do a `sudo service apache2 restart` please and try it again

Comment: I did the mv command and  it says that the file already exists in that directory /var/www/html/phpinfo.php.

Comment: restart did not fix it, What about the command sudo touch /var/www//html/phpinfo.php. Could have that one affected something?

Comment: Meh. What does `sudo apache2ctl -M | grep php` give ya? Trying to find out if php5_module was loaded. My suspicion: apache2ctl -M won't list php5_module. I think the tutorial is bogus. If php5_module wasn't installed automatically, it can't work. See this tutorial, where they install it: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Sorry guys. I fell asleept. it was 330am here in costa rica.  by the way I am talking through the stack exchange mobile app. is cool in case yiu are away from yhe computer. Now, here is what I sm going to do. 11 am going to start it all over. I will havve to use another tutorial. do you guys have any better? but I have questions because I am interested in building my dynamic website...: I was asking people that use Amazon AWS an I Also asked google cloud platform services about ehat

Comment: I waz asking about what I can do woth their services. but if I sss able to build my own website and host it myself it would be great. do.you guys think I could do it using the Ubuntu  server LAMP pñatfotm only? or you suggest somehting better?

Comment: Put `127.0.1.1 UBUNTUSERVER` in `/etc/host` to suppress the message from the first screenshot - http://askubuntu.com/questions/811098/when-i-run-a-sudo-command-it-says-unable-to-resolve-host/811113#811113

Answer (score 1):

[image]

- I found what the error was!.
- The Address I was putting was the loopback one, I typed the Static from the Server I finally got it.
- That was the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this. Right now I am having exactly the same problem. Could you please tell me, wheat "the Sttic from the Server" means, and where can I find it?