# When I run a sudo command it says unable to resolve host

Tags: command-line

And when I tried the following commands `/etc/hostnames` and `/etc/hosts`, it says:

```
bash: permission denied.
```

Comment: `/etc/hostnames` and `/etc/hosts` are not commands.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To to resolve *a host*, just add *it* to `/etc/hosts`, like the example below.

[image: Animated example]

<sup>Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save the edits and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit from Nano. Here you are and [screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTlkU.png).</sup>

In this example is assumed that the [hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) (SZS in this case) is correct, but it is not bound to the server's IP address via server's [hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file.

---

To resolve this issue you must find (or set) your `hostname` and insert next line into `/etc/host`:

```
127.0.1.1    your-hostname
```

The commands used in the example are:

```
cat /etc/hostname      # the command 'cat' will print the content of '/etc/hostname' file
hostname               # without arguments, this command will do the same as above command
cat /etc/hosts         # will print the content of '/etc/hosts' file
sudo nano /etc/hosts   # 'nano' text editor will open '/etc/hosts' as root
```

Here you are, few more approaches and explanations:

- [Another answer of this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/811106/566421);
- [Another answer of similar question](https://askubuntu.com/a/59517/566421);
- [Example how to be append the `hostname` in `/etc/hosts` through single command via commandline](https://superuser.com/a/1117435/664884) and [Example how to find your current IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322485/how-to-i-get-the-primary-ip-address-of-the-local-machine-on-linux-and-os-x);
- [Bug discussion about this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/32906);
- [A brief explanation of `/etc/hosts/` purpose](https://askubuntu.com/a/183187/566421).

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you're on Ubuntu Server.

`/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` are files. You can use `nano` or `pico` to edit them if you're new to the OS. These files are owned by root, thus you need to use `sudo` to edit them.

Thus, the full command would be `sudo nano /etc/hosts` or `sudo nano /etc/hostname`

If you're on Ubuntu Server it's more advisable to use `sudo hostname your.fqdn.com`. This will automatically update the `/etc/hostname` file, however, if it doesn't you can always add the FQDN of your server into that file.

You will need to log out / log in to SSH to have these changes take effect for your session.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `sudo -i gedit /etc/hosts`.

To edit the file in the terminal itself, use `sudo vim /etc/hosts` (advanced).

If you break something in this file, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482210/i-messed-up-my-etc-hosts-and-etc-resolv-conf-files-now-my-network-doesnt-wor)'s a fix.

Comment: It still says that tho,i tried to modify it with my current usernam because i mispelled it when i typed it the first time but it says sudo: unable to resolve host joli3-hp-g62-notebook-pc

(gedit:9316): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

** (gedit:9316): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-enabled not supported