# How to configure Apache to Multiple subdomains

Tags: apache2

I have various differentes subdomains pointing to same directory/application in my apache 2.2.

Like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName subdomain1.domain.com.br
ServerAdmin ti@domain.com.br
DocumentRoot /var/www/application
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName subdomain2.domain.com.br
ServerAdmin ti@domain.com.br
DocumentRoot /var/www/application
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is to configure apache every subdomain is added in DNS Server.

Its possible to have only one virtualhost, representing all subdomains ?

Something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName *.domain.com.br
ServerAdmin ti@domain.com.br
DocumentRoot /var/www/application
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but in the article [VirtualHost Examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) is no mentioned syntax like `ServerName *.domain.com.br`. In this case you have to use [ServerAlias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias) directive, and the VirtualHost configuration should be something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com.br
    ServerAlias *.domain.com.br

    ServerAdmin ti@domain.com.br
    DocumentRoot /var/www/application
</VirtualHost>
```

Please note that the directive ServerAlias can be used only in the virtual host context.

I think in the case when all of your sub-domains points to one DocumentRoot folder, if you set ServerName in server context the result will be almost the same:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com.br
    ServerAlias *.domain.com.br

    ServerAdmin ti@domain.com.br
    DocumentRoot /var/www/application
</VirtualHost>
```

In this case you must enter in [`/etc/hosts`](https://askubuntu.com/a/811113/566421) following:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  domain.com.br
```

Where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is your server's IP address.

Comment: tks Spas Spasov works perfectly!