# How to set a domain to ip address?

Tags: networking, apache2, dns

You can reach this IP address [2.186.116.46](http://2.186.116.46) (if my computer is online). I want to assign a domain to it so I wonder how is that possible when I have no DNS? I do own my domain which is ".com". My IP is static.

Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of free DNS providers. If you don't want to use them, you'll need to edit the /etc/hosts file on each computer that uses the IP address.

Comment: So how can I use them?

Comment: It looks like you using Apache/2.4.7. So in short: 1st you have to acquire [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) from some [DNS provider](http://www.dot.tk/en/index.html?lang=en). 2nd: you must setup a [`ServerName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) directive into your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/your-virtualhost.conf` file.

Comment: If this is just for your use, I highly recommend https://freedns.afraid.org/. You can either use a custom domain that you get elsewhere, or you can take a subdomain of any of their thousands. The guy who runs it is also very friendly and has helped me with some of my DNS problems.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**1.** You need to acquire [a domain name](https://serverfault.com/questions/269838/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hostname-and-a-fully-qualified-domain-name) (or maybe just [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name)) from some [DNS provider](https://www.google.com/search?q=domain%20name).

**2.** Once you have registered the domain name, you will gain access to an administrative panel (like this one shown below), where you will be able (via A records), to redirect the domain name (and all `*.` or certain sub domains / FQDNs) to your server's IP address.

[image]

- Please note that the provider's administrative panel shall looks different, and the provider will give you exact instructions how to use it.
- Sometimes the redirection can take up-to 24 hours. You can check if it's successful by the command `whois example.com`.
- If the server is behind NAT, you must setup [port forwarding](https://askubuntu.com/a/876062/566421).

**3.** Edit your [Virtual Host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) configuration file and add relevant `ServerName` and maybe `ServerAlias` directives. Let's assume the configuration file is `000-default.conf` that should look as this:

```bsh
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com localhost

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                # etc ...
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

- This step can be omitted, but it is absolutely necessary when you have [**more than one Virtual Hosts**](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031607/566421).
- Don't forgot to:

  ```
  sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf
  sudo systemctl reload apache2.service
  ```

**4.** In addition for [*local needs*](https://askubuntu.com/a/941305/566421):

- You can bind a FQDN to the loopback interface of the server. For this purpose, [edit](https://askubuntu.com/a/811113/566421) the file `/etc/hosts` in a way like this:

  ```
  127.0.0.1    localhost example.com www.example.com
  ```

  It is not possible to enter `*.example.com` here. You can add an entry also for the IP address of another (local) server's network [interface](https://www.google.bg/search?q=difference%20between%20127.0.0.1%20and%200.0.0.0&oq=difference%20between%20127.0.0.&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0.12475j1j9&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - for example `77.77.77.70`.
- If you want to access the FQDN by another computer through the LAN (or by a private computer through Internet), edit its `host` file in a way like this:

  ```
  77.77.77.70    example.com www.example.com
  ```

---

Further reading:

- [Creating additional virtual host Ubuntu Server 16.04.3](https://askubuntu.com/q/1031543/566421)
- [Connect via ssh to one of the multiple clients on same network](https://askubuntu.com/q/876046/566421)

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/811416/566421) could be interesting for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But editing my /etc/hosts will only make domain available for my home network I want to set domain for public internet connection. I now got two DNS: herahost1.ddns.net herahost2.ddns.net shall I set them to my domain? But when I even do it the domain won't redirect to my site!

Comment: Thanks, Would you please give an screenshot of your sub domain setting which you set it to mine?

Comment: Thanks for your kindness, I exactly did right that but it's not working. And my bigger problem is that what shall I set the DNS of my domain. when I try to set them in herahost1.ddns.com and herahost2.ddns.com which are set to my ip it says something went wrong!

Comment: And this is my screen of settings [link](http://2.186.116.46/Selection_041.png)

Comment: In my provider's documentation is written that I must have at least one `A` and one `MX` record for the base domain name and for all (`*.`) subdomains - first four lines from the screenshot. The two Nameservers are defined into [another page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W73tJ.png). Also I was waiting about 20 hours for the initial redirection to my IP address because many domain servers on the Internet need to be updated. About your screenshot - record number 3 is not needed, because 127.0.0.1 is the [Loopback interface](http://askubuntu.com/a/247626/566421) which represents the current machine.

Answer (score 6):

If it is for just local use, you can just put that entry into your hosts file.

On modern Windows, that is usually `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`.

On Linux, the file is `/etc/hosts`.

For the rest of the world, use one of the freely available DNS providers.

Here is an example, with instructions:  [FreeDNS](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/536/51/how-do-i-set-my-domain-to-use-namecheaps-freedns-service)