# Setting up vhost on VirtualBox with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, virtualbox, apache2

I am pretty new to development and this is why I am stuck at such a "beginners" problem.

I want to have a directory under */var/www/mysite* with a *index.html* and access it via web browser on my PC (Win10 64 Bit) by typing *mysite.example* into it.

I don't want to publish anything into the internet with that. I only want to test and develop a site which later might be hosted.

I have created a VirtualMachine using Oracle VirtualBox and installed Ubuntu16.04 (64-Bit, also enabled Virtualization at my i5 2500 in Bios so I get these 64-Bit displayed).

Then I installed *apache2*, *mysql* and *php*.

`ip addr show` gave me an address: *192.168.178.31*.

So if I type into my browser `http://192.168.178.31/` I get to the apache2 default page - It works!

I created the directory */var/www/mysite* and put a simple *index.html* for testing purpouse into it. I said `sudo chown -R 775 to /var/www/`.

Now I need to create a vhost so I can access to this *index.html* in this specific directory by typing in a specific string into my browser. But it just won't work!

I went to */etc/apache2/sites-available/* and created *mysite.conf*.

This is the content:

```
<VirtualHost *80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
ServerAlias mysite.example
</VirtualHost>
```

I did `a2ensite mysite.conf`, `sudo service apache2 reload` and `restart`

So there I am. If I type *mysite.example* into my browser I only get errors.

Site not reached. DNS-Server for mysite.example not found and so on (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that if you are using `mysite.local` instead of `mysite.org`* (or other popular extension) you may type `http://` in front of it every time, because the browser may not recognise `.local` as a domain extension.

- `.google`, `.dev`, `.foo`, `.page`, `.app`, `.chrome` domain extensions are not good idea for similar purposes since December 2017, [read more](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/)... [and more](https://askubuntu.com/a/985300/566421)...

If you want to access `mysite.local` and `www.mysite.local` from the local machine, edit `/etc/hosts` and bind these two domain names to the loopback interface - `127.0.0.1`:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost mysite.local www.mysite.local
```

- Add this line somewhere inside of `/etc/hosts`.
- Note that, in this context the local 'machine' is the Virtual Machine with Ubuntu.

If you want to access `mysite.local` through another computer from your LAN, edit its `host` file and bind the two domain names to the servers IP address:

```
192.168.178.31    mysite.local www.mysite.local
```

- [How to Edit Your Hosts File on Windows, Mac, or Linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/)
- The host computer that runs Oracle VirtualBox must be regarded as machine from the virtual LAN, that you've created during the setup of VirtualBox.

---

Another option is to create your local DNS:

- [How To Configure BIND as a Private Network DNS Server on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)

---

Here is a basic virtual host configuration applicable for your case:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName mysite.local
        ServerAlias www.mysite.local

        ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.local

        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite

        <Directory /var/www/mysite>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AuthType None
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.local-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysite.local-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

- In the beginning put some basic content in `/var/www/mysite`. The function `phpinfo();` is a good idea:

  ```
    echo '<?php phpinfo(); ?>' | sudo tee /var/www/mysite/index.php
  ```

Restart Apache and try to access `http://mysite.local` via the browser.

---

**Read also:**

- [Virtual Host not working as expected when I'm using .dev domain extension](https://askubuntu.com/q/1024957/566421)
- [Creating additional Virtual Host Ubuntu Server](https://askubuntu.com/q/1031543/566421)

Comment: Hello pa4080! Thank you for you answer! I have followed your instructions step by step but I still cannot really visit the site via browser on my local machine. It now says ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED as I try to visit the site.

Comment: Hi, @nico, what you meant when said "local machine" - Ubuntu inside the VirtualBox - or the computer that runs Oracle VirtualBox?

Comment: The PC that runs the VirtualBox. Sorry for beeing not clear :(

Comment: Have you included the line `192.168.178.31 mysite.dev www.mysite.dev` into its `hosts` file, @nico? Within the above context it is a machine from your 'virtual` LAN, and the local machine is the virtual Ubuntu system. Apparently I must clarify this in the answer.

Comment: Alright, now I have got it! At least I'm pretty close! Now I get the apache2 Ubuntu Default Page on http://mysite.dev, which I don't really unterstand. I have rechecked the mysite.conf and de Docroot is correct /var/www/mysite/

Comment: Hm, please check the permissions of the directory `/var/www/mysite/` and its content they must be similar as these of `/var/www/html/`. Also check the names of all paths carefully. Don't forgot to **restart (or reload) Apache** after each configuration change! Did you edit `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` for any reason?

Comment: This post right here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713061/virtualhost-always-returns-default-host-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04 got me thinking, I deleted my .conf in sites-available and in sites-enabled, started all from new. Now it finally work! Thank you very much for helping me out with this!