# Cannot access local webpage (error: could not resolve host)

Tags: server, apache2

This is exactly what I have set up right now:

```
cd /var/www
mkdir -p test
cd /var/www/test
sudo nano index.html
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
sudo nano test.conf
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost223.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
</VirtualHost>
```

```
$sudo a2ensite test.conf
$sudo service apache2 reload
```

I can access my page like this:`file:///var/www/test/index.html` in web browser.

```
<html>
    <h1>
         here
    </h1>
</html>
```

But I cannot do access: `http://localhost223.com`

I get the error: `Could not resolve host`

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you put `127.0.0.1   localhost223.com` in the `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: I shouldn't need to but I will try that aswell,
I have tried 127.0.1.2 localhost223.com but that just returns the default apache page.

Comment: @George just did "127.0.0.1 localhost223.com" in /etc/hosts file. Did nothing but return the default localhost page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @George said, while there is no [FQDN that points to your server's IP](https://askubuntu.com/a/900594/566421),  you need to [bind the domain name with the loopback interface](https://askubuntu.com/a/941305/566421) - `127.0.0.1`, through the next line in the `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost223.com
```

Then edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/test.conf` in this way:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName localhost223.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test

        <Directory /var/www/test>
                Options None FollowSymLinks
                # Enable .htaccess Overrides:
                AllowOverride All
                DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forgot to `sudo a2ensite test.conf`, then restart the web server:

- Ubuntu 14.04: `sudo service apache2 restart`
- Ubuntu 16.04: `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`

Try to access your page through the browser.

Comment: U don't know how long I have been trying to get this to work! Thank you! Finally it works!

Comment: Happy to help, @DR.Palson_PH.d!

Comment: This works for me when I have access localhost223.com in my ubuntu VM using a web browser. But when I access localhost223.com on my windows machine (I use port forwarding to access) it does not work. I can access localhost fine from outside my VM using port forwarding, but I get server not found error when I try localhost223.com. Any ideas?

Comment: @DR.Palson_PH.d : Yes I have an idea :) You should add this line: `<ubuntu-virtual-lan-ip>    localhost223.com` into your `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` file. For more detailed answer, please, [check here](https://askubuntu.com/a/941305/566421).

Comment: And maybe [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/941947/566421) is also good example.

Comment: thanks again. Much appreciated. I wonder how localhost still works without having to do that.