# How do you set up Let's Encrypt SSL certificates for additional ports in Apache?

Tags: server, apache2, debian, ssl, certificates

I would like to find out how to set up Let's Encrypt on an Apache2 web server on ports that are not 443. In the past, I have been successful in the past using CertBot to automatically set up port 443. However, I would like to find out a way to use Let's Encrypt to set up SSL on ports such as 99 or 8080, for example.

Since there is no easy way to set up certificates on non default ports using Let's Encrypt Certbot, how would I go about manually setting up Let's Encrypt certificates on non default ports?

Comment: **"I don't even know what I'm trying to do"**: and yet you say it's simple!

Comment: I'm referring to the silliness of my situation.

Comment: I know but don't beat yourself up it happens to all of us and no situation is ever so simple, if it were we won't learn a thing :)

Comment: What do you mean by "other ports"?

Comment: I refer to ports that are not 443 or 80

Comment: By the way, Debian is off-topic here. @George, should we flag the question?

Comment: @pa4080 i didn't see that, yes flag it...

Answer (score 3):

You make modifications in apache's `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` to inform apache to listen on these different ports:

```
Listen 8080
<IfModule ssl_module>            
        Listen 446
</IfModule>
```

The steps would be:

1. Create your SSL certificates:

   - Make directory to add certificates:

     ```
     mkdir -p /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com
     ```
   - Create a self signed certificate:

     ```
     sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/apache.key –out /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/apache.crt
     ```
2. Enable the ssl module with: `sudo a2enmod ssl`
3. Make entries in your `Virtualhost` files ( called example.conf ), with `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.conf`

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:8080>
       ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
       ServerName example.com
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html

   </VirtualHost>


   <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
   <VirtualHost *:446>

       ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
       ServerName example.com
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html

       #   SSL Engine Switch:
       #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
       SSLEngine on

       #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
       #   the ssl-cert package. See
       #   /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz for more info.
       #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
       #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
       SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/apache.crt
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/apache.key
   </VirtualHost>

   </IfModule>
   ```
4. Tell apache to listen in the new ports by adding the ports to `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` file:

   ```
   Listen 8080
   <IfModule ssl_module>            
       Listen 446
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
       Listen 446
   </IfModule>
   ```

   - This tells apache to listen for SSL traffic on port `446` as against `443`
5. Enable the config files:

   ```
   sudo a2ensite example
   ```
6. Restart apache:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart apache2
   ```

Comment: Do you know how to do the same for web applications already using these ports?

Comment: What applications are these?

Comment: I refer to shellinabox, emby, and webmin

Comment: Refer to their individual config files to change the listening ports then add it to the apache config files

Answer (score 3):

First you should read these answers:

- [How to setup an additional VirtualHost](https://askubuntu.com/a/949315/566421)
- [Change phpMyAdmin port from 80 to another number](https://askubuntu.com/a/897133/566421)
- [How to create and enable Let's Encrypt HTTPS certificate](https://askubuntu.com/a/900433/566421)

Based on the above answers the steps are:

- Create a new VirtualHost configuration file, dedicated to your additional port. Let's assume this is port `99`, and the configuration file name is `https-99.conf`:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/https-99.conf
  ```

  The content of `https-99.conf` should look like this:

  ```
  <IfModule mod_ssl.c>

  Listen 99

  <VirtualHost *:99>

          ServerName www.example.com

          DocumentRoot /var/www/html-99

          <Directory /var/www/html-99>
                  Options None FollowSymLinks
                  AllowOverride None
                  # To enable .htaccess Overrides: AllowOverride All
                  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
                  Order allow,deny
                  Allow from all
                  Require all granted
          </Directory>

          ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/https-99.error.log
          CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/https-99.access.log combined

          SSLEngine on
          SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/cert.pem
          SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
          SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/chain.pem

  </VirtualHost>

  </IfModule>
  ```

  *Copy the above content and in `nano` use: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> for paste; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> for save; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> for exit.*
- Enable the configuration file:

  ```
  sudo a2ensite https-99.conf
  ```
- Generate [Let's Encrypt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/letsencrypt.1.html) certificate files:

  ```
  sudo letsencrypt --apache certonly --rsa-key-size 4096 --email email@example.com -d www.example.com
  ```

  Where `email@example.com` and `www.example.com` must be real.
- Open port `99` into the firewall:

  - If you use [UFW](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) you can do that by this command: `sudo ufw allow 99/tcp`
  - If you use [IPTables](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-basic-iptables-firewall-on-centos-6): `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 99 -j ACCEPT`
- Create the `DocumentRoot` directory:

  ```
  sudo mkdir /var/www/html-99
  ```
- Put some simple content in the `DocumentRoot` directory:

  ```
  echo 'Hello!!!' | sudo tee /var/www/html-99/index.html
  ```
- Reload Apache's configuration:

  - Ubuntu 14.04: `sudo service apache2 reload`
  - Ubuntu 16.04: `sudo systemctl reload apache2.service`
- Try to open `https://www.example.com:99` via the browser. The result should be:

  [image]

Comment: `letsencrypt` / `python-letsencrypt-apache` is available for Ubuntu 16.04 and above, for the previous versions there is [**`certbot`**](https://certbot.eff.org/) which is almost the same. From [Ubuntu Manuals](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/letsencrypt.1.html). Sert