# Where to point the browser to when using Virtual Host?

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

When using Virtual Host, where should I point my browser to?

I'm trying to set up Virtual Host for `Example.com`. My understanding is that if all good, I have to point the browser to `Example.com/phptest.php` in order to access page `phptest.php`. But it's not working. On the other hand, if I point the browser to `localhost/phptest.php`, it is returning the `phptest.php` page.

The pertaining directory/files structure is as below.

```
ls -l /var/www/html/example.com/public_html
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 203 Nov 25 14:49 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  21 Nov 25 18:56 info2.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 641 Nov 25 13:48 phptest.php
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, you need to add `127.0.0.1 example.com` in your `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot access local webpage (error: could not resolve host)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/949194/cannot-access-local-webpage-error-could-not-resolve-host) **Please, read carefully also the two answers, linked at the beginning of the accepted answer.**

Comment: After you create a vhost, you need to edit your /etc/hosts file to ponit your local ip (127.0.0.1 to Example.com) because example.com is not a valid domain of your property.

Comment: @pa4080: Adding 127.0.0.1 example.com in /etc/hosts file solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `127.0.0.1 example.com` in `/etc/hosts` file solves the problem.

The browser should be pointing to `http://example.com/phptest.php`.

**Note:** Make sure that the **server-name variable in the php script** accessing MySQL (`phptest.php` in our case) is set to "example.com".