# NXDOMAIN named based virtualhost

Tags: server, apache2, dns

I'm having trouble to configure a new named based virtualServer on my server and i can't figure out why, any help would be most welcome....

So i have this server where a virtual server, there named prealp.msh-alpes.fr is working very well. I need to add a new virtualserver named enquetes-screen.msh-alpes.fr. I created a file in /var/www/enquetes-screen, chmod it in 755 the configure the rest like this :

my /etc/hosts file :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
195.221.00.00   tyrion.msh-alpes.fr tyrion
195.221.00.00   prealp.msh-alpes.fr prealp
195.221.00.00   enquetes-screen.msh-alpes.fr    enquetes-screen.msh-alpes.fr
```

My /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 152.77.00.00
nameserver 195.83.00.00
search msh-alpes.fr enquetes-screen.msh-alpes.fr
```

So this is my conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/prealp.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin     webmaster@msh-alpes.fr
        DocumentRoot    /var/www/prealp
        ServerName  prealp.msh-alpes.fr

        <Directory /var/www/prealp>
                Options -Indexes
                AllowOverride  All 
        </Directory>

    LogLevel warn

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-prealp.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-prealp.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin     webmaster@msh-alpes.fr
        DocumentRoot    /var/www/file
        ServerName      enquetes-screen.msh-alpes.fr

        <Directory /var/www/limesurvey>
                Options -Indexes
                AllowOverride  All
        </Directory>

        LogLevel warn

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-limesurvey.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-limesurvey.log combined

</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin     webmaster@msh-alpes.fr
        DocumentRoot    /var/www/prealp
        ServerName  prealp.msh-alpes.fr

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/cert-28559-prealp.msh-alpes.fr.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/prealp.msh-alpes.fr.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/chain-28559-prealp.msh-alpes.fr.pem

        <Directory /var/www/prealp>
                Options -Indexes
                AllowOverride  All 
        </Directory>

    LogLevel warn

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-prealp-ssl.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-prealp-ssl.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName 
    enquetes-screen.msh-alpes.fr
        ServerAlias www.enquetes-screen.msh-alpes.fr
        ServerAdmin admin@msh-alpes.fr
        DocumentRoot /var/www/file

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/enquetes-screen_msh-alpes_fr.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/enquetes-screen.msh-alpes.fr.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/DigiCertCA.crt

        LogLevel warn

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-enquetes-screen-ssl.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access-enquetes-screen-ssl.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I also tried to separate into two conf file site1.conf and newsite.conf without success

The result of `apache2ctl -t` return a syntax ok.

Then `a2ensite prealp.conf` and `/etc/init.d/apache2 reload` are going fine too.

the result of `apachectl -S` return

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server analytics.msh-alpes.fr (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/analytics.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost analytics.msh-alpes.fr (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/analytics.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost prealp.msh-alpes.fr (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/prealp.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost enquetes-screen.msh-alpes.fr (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/prealp.conf:19)
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server prealp.msh-alpes.fr (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/prealp.conf:38)
         port 443 namevhost prealp.msh-alpes.fr (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/prealp.conf:38)
         port 443 namevhost enquetes-screen.msh-alpes.fr (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/prealp.conf:61)
                 alias www.enquetes-screen.msh-alpes.fr
```

but the `nslookup enquetes-screen.msh-alpes.fr` still return

```
** server can't find enquetes-screen.msh-alpes.fr: NXDOMAIN
```

I've been looking for a while now and i have no idea why this doesn't work....Is there something obvious i'm missing ? i'm quite new to this so any help would be most welcome...

Comment: Probably you should buy and setup `enquetes-screen.msh-alpes.fr`. Related topics: https://askubuntu.com/q/900523/566421 and https://askubuntu.com/q/941299/566421