# accessing localhost in virtualbox (ubuntu)

Tags: networking, 18.04, virtualbox, hosts

How can I access my virtual host like `http://copywriters.localhost`
inside my Windows 10 VirtualBox?

I already set this:

In VM Host File:

```
10.0.2.2 localhost
10.0.2.2 copywriters.localhost
```

In my Host PC:

```
127.0.0.1 copywriters.localhost
```

I can ping `http://copywriters.localhost` in VM. But can access on browser.

Comment: Virtualbox treats Host and Guest like two independent systems on a network: localhost ports on system A cannot be seen by applications on system B. Vbox Guest Additions will permit you to share the filesystem on the host, but not ports.

Comment: Don’t replace the default `localhost` with a different address (`10.0.2.2 localhost`)! Can you connect to your host system using the IP address?

Comment: @Melebius I can connect with my phpmyadmin `http://10.0.2.2/phpmyadmin` but can't connect using this `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` in my VM

Comment: In this case, the line `10.0.2.2 copywriters.localhost` should be sufficient AFAIK.

Comment: `127.0.0.1 copywriters.localhost`is not correct.  Assuming it's a bridged network, you need the same `10.0.2.2 copywriters.localhost` rule.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up vhost on VirtualBox with Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941299/setting-up-vhost-on-virtualbox-with-ubuntu-16-04)