# How to add my dns to the public network

Tags: apache2, dns, websites

I have just created a new page on my virtual machine Linux and configured DNS for this page. It works only if user sets DNS to my Linux address. I want user to be able to visit my page on whatever DNS he has, lets say Google one - 8.8.8.8.
How to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a domain to ip address?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900523/how-to-set-a-domain-to-ip-address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to buy/register domain, and make a dns hosting on your own servers or domain hosting service. If you want to host domain on your own server you should provide information about your dns hosting to registar, but this is difficult and better to choose service. Google for dns hosting and find a service.

You can't create domain for free. You need to buy it from registrar and submit them information about your dns servers. Then other dns servers will also known your domain.

There are a registrar what give domain for free or small price, but you should look carefully how they will charge you on next year.

You can get domain name for free, but it will be third level of domain. Like yourname.holder.com.

Comment: I do not mind it is difficult or not, I just want to learn how to do most things on my own computer. I think I did not get everything clear, mostly the second part of your answer. Why I cannot get domain name for free? For now lets say I have already registered a domain. How to make dns hosting using bind9? I have already configured my dns for local network.

Comment: @JarekBisnesu updated answer

Comment: I never do self hosting of domains so not tell you how to configure bind, but may find a right howto on google. One thing what different is how to communicate with registrar. I`ll update question once again about free domains

Comment: Ok, so I have just created a domain for free without adding my bank account, so they cannot charge me next year I guess, I will look deeper a bit later and I can add there a new DNS record. I added new DNS record with my DNS ip, but it does not work, I am wondering, I have to pass there my DNS(linux machine) ip or my network ip (provided by my network operator)?

Comment: Public static ip, provided by network operator but static(should be additional fee)

Comment: I think I know everything I wanted, thank you for help