# cannot access Apache2 website from external network

Tags: 18.04, apache2

Recently I use Apache2 to build a website on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. I can successfully access my website via both IP and domain through the server itself and other devices under the same network. However, I cannot visit my website through cellular networks. This is my website domain: doubilab.com. This is my IP: 131.128.54.59.

The status of the Apache server is as follows: [Apache2 Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWHy6.png)

Notice that the firewall is inactive.

Comment: This requires a bit more than just enabling apache. You have to set port-forwarding on your router, and also have public IP.

Comment: @JohnRonald Thanks for your answer. I believe this is a public IP. But I have a question about the port-forwarding. Before I install Apache2, I can access my machine via SSH from external network. But now I cannot. Why did this happen?

Comment: That's hard to say without any logs or additional information provided. Are you sure your SSH service is running ?

Comment: @JohnRonald I just test another Ubuntu server under the same network, which could be accessed via SSH from the external network. But my machine cannot. Can you tell me some orders so that I can provide some logs?

Comment: First try to find out if Apache is what blocks your SSH connections. (Which is pretty unlike ). So disable Apache and try SSH again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a domain to ip address?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900523/how-to-set-a-domain-to-ip-address)